# Working with column containing tilde separated data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column in a table which contains tilde separated data.

I want to fire a SINGLE sql query (for performance reasons) which should return me all the records in the table for which at least one token in this tilde separated data is not in a predefined list of valid values.

I had looked for the solution in various forums and most of them said to have a user defined split function to split the records or use some regular expressions but that won't work with a single query.

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions to parse the data in a single SQL statement.  You can then apply whatever filters you would like to find the set of values that are not in a predefined list

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with test as
  2    (select 'ABC~DEF~GHI~JKL~MNO' str from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr (str, '[^~]+', 1, rownum) split
  4    from test
  5* connect by level <= length (regexp_replace (str, '[^~]+'))  + 1
SQL> /

SPLIT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
```

You can also do something like this

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with test as
  2    (select 1 id, 'ABC~DEF~GHI~JKL~MNO' str from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'XY~PDQ~435' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'This~is~a~test' from dual)
  5  select id, regexp_substr (str, '[^~]+', 1, e.lvl) split
  6    from test,
  7         (select level lvl
  8            from dual
  9         connect by level <= (select max(regexp_count(str,'~')) + 1
 10                                from test)) e
 11*  where regexp_substr (str, '[^~]+', 1, e.lvl) is not null
SQL> /

        ID SPLIT
---------- --------------------
         1 ABC
         2 XY
         3 This
         1 DEF
         2 PDQ
         3 is
         1 GHI
         2 435
         3 a
         1 JKL
         3 test
         1 MNO

12 rows selected.
```

Of course, this is not going to be particularly efficient-- you're going to have to do a full scan of the table since you're not going to be able to effectively index the various substrings.  There are other ways to generate the rows as well-- Rob van Wijk has an article that compares the performance of various [interval based row generation techniques](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2007/11/interval-based-row-generation.html) in his blog.

You would generally be much better off fixing your data model.  Storing delimited data in a column violates basic normalization principles.  If you had stored the data in a separate column (presumably in a separate table that has a 1 to many relationship with the existing table), you could index the data and you could create a foreign key constraint that maps to the predefined list of valid values so you can prevent invalid data from being inserted in the first place (or at least prevent new invalid rows from being added in the future).

Comment: +1 for "*You would generally be much better off fixing your data model*"